# Drupal PHP serialize and unserialize

Tags: php, drupal, serialization

In Drupal, I first serialized emails that appear in the body of private messages and stored them is MySQL like this:

```
function prvtmsg_list($body) {
  $notify = array();
  if (isset($body->emails)) {
    $notify['mid'] = $body->mid;
    $notify['emails'] = serialize($body->emails);
  }
  if (isset($body->vulgar_words) {
    $notify['mid'] = $body->mid;
    $notify['vulgar_words'] = serialize($message->vulgar_words);
  }
  if (isset($notify['mid'])) {
    drupal_write_record('prvtmsg_notify', $notify);
  }
}
```

When I later try to retrieve them, email userialization fails, I retrieve them like this:

```
function prvtmsg_list_notify() {
  // Select fields from prvtmsg_notify and Drupal pm_message tables
  $query = db_select('prvtmsg_notify', 'n');
  $query->leftJoin('pm_message', 'm', 'n.mid = m.mid');
  $query->fields('n', array('mid', 'emails', 'vulgar_words'));
  $query->fields('m', array('mid', 'author', 'subject', 'body', 'timestamp'));
  orderBy('timestamp', 'DESC');
  $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(20);
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

  $rows = array();
  foreach ($result as $notify) {
    $rows[] = array(
      $notify->author,
      $notify->subject,
      implode(', ', unserialize($notify->emails)),
      implode(', ', unserialize($notify->vulgar_words)),
    );
  }

  $build = array();
  $build['table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => array(
      t('Author'),
      t('Message subject'),
      t('Emails captured'),
      t('Vulgar Words Captured'),
    ),
    '#rows' => $rows,
  );
  $build['pager']['#theme'] = 'pager';

  return $build;
```

}

Maybe the way I serialized the emails is wrong? because:

```
dpm(unserialize($notify->emails);
```

gives Array, Array, Array - which means:

`Array(
  [0] => Array() [1] => Array() [2] => Array() [3] => Array()
)`

Surprisingly, the unserialized vulgar words are showing okay! I'm not sure is it possible to serialize the emails like this:

```
$notify['emails'] = serialize (array($body->emails));
```

I faced the exact situation in the past where unserialization did not work for me, there is something not clear to me and I need to learn it. Could anyone confirm or tell me what's wrong?

N.B. The above code is from memory and may not be accurate as I currently don't have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

if i am reading this correctly you are writing an array into a db

```
drupal_write_record('prvtmsg_notify', $notify);
```

should be:

```
drupal_write_record('prvtmsg_notify', serialize($notify));
```

you will most likely no longer need

```
$notify['emails'] = serialize($body->emails);
```

and can instead write:

```
$notify['emails'] = $body->emails;
```

after retrieving it from the db you can unserialize the array and iterate over it ex:

```
$array = unserialize(someFunctionToGetPrvtmsg_notifyFromTheDb());
//the array should be the same as the one you serialized
```

Comment: thank you. the $notify array holds the mid, emails, and also other things not shown in the code which will be inserted in multiple fields. I will edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: the $notify array holds things other than the emails which don't need to be serialized.